# What do Starfleet's dress uniforms look like in Star Trek: Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

What do Starfleet dress uniforms look like during the time of Star Trek: Discovery [DISC]? Do we have any idea based on the canon, supplementary material, or even concept art? Every other series has designed unique dress uniforms for Starfleet, but as far as I can tell DISC doesn't have any.

Comment: Apparently they all just slob around in their day uniforms, even when they go to formal events like medal ceremonies.

Comment: It appears like in the 32nd century that the grey uniform might possibly be a dress uniform. The trailer for season 4 shows them wearing much more colourful uniforms

Comment: @SpacePhoenix That's not a bad theory! I figured they just rushed out the gray uniforms and decided to change them after wrapping up Season 3, but they very well could be dress uniforms.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, it was after seeing pictures of their award ceremonies that the question started rattling in my head! I thought it was odd. You may argue it's something do with "demilitarizing" Starfleet, but given how militaristic everything else about DISC's era and uniforms are I doubt that was actually the case. I guess they just didn't design dress uniforms!

Comment: @rr_cola - They seem to be running Discovery as a 'loss leader', designed to get people to sign up for the streaming service, even if it's not actually that popular or successful financially. As such, they're cutting all sorts of corners on costume design, set design, merchandising, etc.

Comment: @Valorum I mean I just figure it's more that they didn't think about it. They should have, it's a huge oversight, but I get it. Every other show has really inconsistent detail when it comes to stuff like enlisted ranks, yet we know they're out there.

Comment: @rr_cola - I'm sure they thought about it extensively, then decided to cheap out.